# Download file uploaded on slack

Tags: c#, slack-api, slack

I have created a .Net Web API which could fetch the file object/details of file which are uploaded on a particular Slack channel.

Urls I have got are:

```
"url_private":"https://files.slack.com/***.png",
"url_private_download":"https://files.slack.com/files-pri/***",
"thumb_64":"https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/***.png",
"thumb_80":"https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/****.png",
"thumb_360":"https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/***.png",
"thumb_360_w":360,
"thumb_360_h":360,
"thumb_160":"https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/***",
"image_exif_rotation":1,
"original_w":400,
"original_h":400,
"permalink":"https://laitkor.slack.com/files/*****/******/***.png",
"permalink_public":"https://slack-files.com/****"
```

How can I download that file from code and save inside a particular folder.
I have read that we need to add Authorization: Bearer A_VALID_TOKEN and I have also done the same:

```
   client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + "********";
   client.DownloadFile(new Uri("*****"),HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + "AttachmentFile_" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy")).Replace("-", "_") + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg"));
```

But here instead of downloading the file, the whole page code is being downloaded when its a txt file and corrupt file is downloaded when its an image file.

Please guide as to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found as to what i was doing wrong.

The Authentication token i was providing was wrong.